# Custom round up to next integer if first decimal point is > 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I round up a float to next integer only if the first digit after decimal is >3.

`my_round(0.0546)` should be 0. `my_round(0.4)` should be 1, `my_round(1.35)` should be 2.

Comment: `round(n + 0.2)` perhaps?

Comment: Never thought about this simple approach. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Take the input as a string or else if you have it as a float convert it to a string using the str().

After making it to a string turn it to be a list.
validate the index second (third position on the list) whether it is greater than or equal to 3 or not.

if yes take the index zero value from the list and change it to int and increment with one or else change to int that it, check the sample code below.

```
x = (input())#with input() the data will be taken as str directly if you have float data convert using str()
lis = list(x)
element = int(lis[2])
if element >=3:
    x = int(lis[0]) + 1
else:
    x = int(lis[0])
print (x)
```

Comment: The number could be large , so third  index position will not always be the first position after decimal. I have applied str split based on ("."), but I think there would be a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, forgot that cause, but you can get the required operation with below code.

```
x = (input())#with input() the data will be taken as str directly if you have float data convert using str()
lis = list(x)

pos = lis.index('.')

element = int(lis[pos+1])
new_lis = lis[0:pos]
final_data = ''.join(new_lis)

if element >=3:
    x = int(final_data) + 1
else:
    x = int(final_data)
print (x)
```

identify the index of '.' and separate a new list until the '.' index and turn it in to a string using .join() operator.

Validate the next value after decimal and increment the value which is formed after join operator.